# "Warning: Async stack traces in debugger" in Node-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a document in my collection of MongoDB. However, when I run the program in the VS-Code IDE, I am being encountered with the following error:

<< C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe .\DBOperations.js
(node:936) [INSPECTOR_ASYNC_STACK_TRACES_NOT_AVAILABLE] Warning: Warning: Async stack traces in debugger are not available on 32bit platforms. The feature is disabled.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Process exited with code 1 >>

MongoDB URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

Same was the error, when I was trying to create a new collection in localHost database of MongoDB.

Please let me know if I need to install any additional Node-JS package (via NPM) or need to update the entire Node-JS version.

Thank you.

Expectation:

1. A record should get inserted in MongoDB Collection.
2. A new collection should get created in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore this warning because it is not causing any problems with your MongoDB operations. The warning is related to the VS Code debugger and doesn't affect the functionality of your program.

The latest available version of Node.js can also be installed if you choose to avoid the warning (https://nodejs.org/). Make sure you're running a 64-bit version of Node.js by following the installation instructions.